# Error 422 (Entidad no procesable) al momento de hacer una solicitud en AJAX

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy usando el framework Laravel. al momento de realizar una solicitud en ajax , si la validación llega a fallar, el usuario recibe un mensaje de error.(Hasta ahí todo me funciona, muestra los mensajes de error y si todo esta bien lo registra) Sin embargo en la consola del navegador al momento que falla la validación salta un error de estado 422  (Unprocessable Entity) Existe una manera para que no se vea ese error ¿ Como podría controlar esos errores ?. No quiero que se muestre en la consola, a continuación les adjuntare las imagenes del código:

**En el controlador**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Ajax**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Respuesta (Si me retorna los mensajes de la validacion)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Pero en la consola sale esto, como podria controlar ese status y no mostrarlo** 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para poder ayudar a solucionar el error necesitamos ver un poco de código, idealmente la solicitud ajax y la parte de backend que entrega la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

El código 422 en Laravel ocurre cuando hay errores de validación (como lo puedes ver en la respuesta que obtienes del servidor), en caso que quieras cambiar dicho código por un 200 por ejemplo, deberás hacer algunos overrides al core de Laravel.

La asignación de dicho código de respuesta se realiza en `Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException`, en las propiedades y también hay un método que permite modificarlo:

```
/**
 * The status code to use for the response.
 *
 * @var int
 */
public $status = 422;

/**
 * Set the HTTP status code to be used for the response.
 *
 * @param  int  $status
 * @return $this
 */

// Omito el resto del código que es innecesario para la explicación

public function status($status)
{
    $this->status = $status;

    return $this;
}
```

Podemos ver claramente como se lanza la excepción en `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest`:

```
/**
 * Handle a failed validation attempt.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator  $validator
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
 */
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    throw (new ValidationException($validator))
                ->errorBag($this->errorBag)
                ->redirectTo($this->getRedirectUrl());
}
```

Y también se encuentra dicho llamado en `Illuminate\Validation\Validator`.

---

Para resolverlo se puede hacer de muchas formas: puedes crear un validador independiente y lanzar la excepción directamente con el código 200, o no lanzar excepción, o crear un FormRequest y hacer el override del método en mención, entre otras opciones.